# moderncv - trying to have more space in the descriptions columns

Tags: formatting, moderncv

I'm using `MacTex 2.7.6`

I have this in my description columns

[image]

I'm looking to have the `Système d'exploitations` and `outils` to go more on the left (see below)

[image]

Please find my MWE (updated version)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font     families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{casual} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % works on MacBook Air (pour mettre en utf-8)
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.5cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column

\firstname{Andy} % Your first name
\familyname{K} % Your last name
\begin{document}
\section{Sélection subjective de mes compétences}
\cvcomputer{Bases de données:}{SQL Server, Oracle, PostgresSQL, MySQL}{Systèmes d'exploitations:}{Windows, Linux/Unix(Mac)}
\cvcomputer{Programmations:}{(T-)SQL, BASH , Python, SAS , HTML , Awk , Sed}{Outils de dév:}{Vim , Git}

\end{document}
```

Please also find the line in `moderncvcompatibility.sty` that is giving me some headache

```
\newcommand*{\cvcomputer}[4]{\cvdoubleitem{#1}{\small#2}{#3}{\small#4}}
```

Comment: item, doubleitem, entry, column, ... hard to guess from a picture, please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Hi @Johannes_B, please find my `MWE`or what I think is my `MWE` on my question.

Comment: Sorry, i should have given you a link: [Preparing a minimal woring example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html). It is also important to know which version you are using.

Comment: @Johannes_B does it make sense?

Comment: @Johannes_B and everyone actually, would it be a way to deal with the `{#3}` and `{\small#4}` and add an extra-size things to say lean to the right?

Comment: Your snippet and your screenshot aren't helpful. Please follow the link above.

Comment: @Johannes_B the text you provided me with , is indigest to me. Sorry. This one is better, still at least to me -> http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: I've updated my `MWE` @Johannes_B

Comment: You can do something like `\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{.07\textwidth}` but that will screw up more than you might expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think there is not so much space you think.  To visualise this I added option `showframe` to the call of `geometry`.

If you now add some more words to your `\cvcomputer` the result looks very different (without changings of the layout!).

If you insist in changing the layout you need to define a new command, for example `\mycvcomputer`.  Then you can change the layout for example to `\raggedright` for the third and fourth column.  Of course you can then also change the space between the columns, but that will not be a good layout with the rest of your cv, I think (my personal opinion!).

To find the original definition of `\cvcomputer` you can find (in your case) in `moderncvbodyi.sty` (see, that `\cvcomputer` is an alias for the command `\cvdoubleitem`).

See the changed MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{casual} % head 2, body 1
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % works on MacBook Air (pour mettre en utf-8)
\usepackage[%
  scale=0.75,                           % Reduce document margins
  showframe                             % shows typing area <===========
]{geometry} 
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.5cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column

\newcommand*{\mycvcomputer}[5][.25em]{% <===============================
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}#3\end{minipage}%
    \hfill% fill of \separatorcolumnwidth
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\hintscolumnwidth}\raggedleft\hintstyle{#4}\end{minipage}%
    \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\doubleitemcolumnwidth}\raggedleft #5\end{minipage}}}

\firstname{Andy} % Your first name
\familyname{K} % Your last name
\begin{document}
\section{Sélection subjective de mes compétences}
\cvcomputer{Bases de données:}{SQL Server, Oracle, PostgresSQL, MySQL}{Systèmes d'exploitations:}{Windows, Linux/Unix(Mac)}
\cvcomputer{Programmations:}{(T-)SQL, BASH , Python, SAS , HTML , Awk , Sed}{Outils de dév:}{Vim , Git}
\cvcomputer{Bases de données:}{SQL Server, Oracle, PostgresSQL, MySQL}{Systèmes d'exploitations:}{Windows, Linux/Unix(Mac), Blafasel, Blafasel, Blafasel, Blafasel}
\mycvcomputer{Bases de données:}{SQL Server, Oracle, PostgresSQL, MySQL}{Systèmes d'exploitations:}{Windows, Linux/Unix(Mac)}
\mycvcomputer{Programmations:}{(T-)SQL, BASH , Python, SAS , HTML , Awk , Sed}{Outils de dév:}{Vim , Git}
\mycvcomputer{Bases de données:}{SQL Server, Oracle, PostgresSQL, MySQL}{Systèmes d'exploitations:}{Windows, Linux/Unix(Mac), Blafasel, Blafasel, Blafasel, Blafasel}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: result of mwe above]